# ListView in JavaFX with data from SQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, javafx

I have a FXML file, on which is ListView and next to it TextFields. How can I synchronize ID's from table on ListView with rest records in table?

For example when I click ID "1" on ListView then NAME and LASTNAME from my database (which are rest records with primary key ID "1") appears in TextField1 and TextField2)

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

db.getConnect();
con = db.getConnect();

try {


    pst1 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT idpatient FROM patient");
    rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();

    while(rs1.next())
    {
    ObservableList<String> ids = FXCollections.observableArrayList(rs1.getString("idpatient"));
    patientList.setItems(ids);
    }
```

This code displays only last row from column "idpatient", but I want to display whole column... how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `patientList.setItems(ids)` for each row returned by the SELECT, so each row throws away the results from the previous row.

You need to accumulate the data from the rows in one list and then call `patientList.setItems(ids)` after the end of the `while(rs1.next())` loop.

Perhaps something like:

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

while(rs1.next())
 {
   results.add(rs1.getString("idpatient"));
 }

ObservableList<String> ids = FXCollections.observableArrayList(results);
patientList.setItems(ids);
```